# How fix MySQL upgrade error after upgrading MAMP/MAMP Pro 4 to 5

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

After upgrading MAMP Pro/MAMP from version 4 to version 5 (5.0.3), I got a pop-up saying that the MySQL databases had to be upgraded, and I clicked the button to do that. Immediately I go the following error:

> mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
>   Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

As a result, it's impossible for me to start the MAMP servers or to open a host.

Following advice from appsolute's Support, in MAMP Pro 5 I changed the MySQL password for user 'root' back to its default value and was able to upgrade the MySQL database(s).

However, after that when I start the drupal5 site in MAMP Pro — and even after I reset the MySQL password for user 'root' in MAMP Pro 5 back to what it should be for the drupal5 database — in the browser page http://drupal5:8888 I get an error message: "Unable to connect to database".

Now there seem to be 3 MySQL databases involved, in folders:

1. /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql/drupal5
2. /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql/mysql
3. /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql57/mysql

Plus, and in accordance with MAMP Pro 5 online documentation, backups of the MySQL database in folders:

4. /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql56/drupal5
5. /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql56/mysql

So the first obvious question is: which database(s) had 'root' passwords changed during the upgrade process? Is either of the two databases "mysql" even involved in loading drupal5?

The second obvious question is: why is there no "drupal5" folder in /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql57 ?

What should I do?